# cancel python script while it's recieving data

Tags: python-2.7, keyboardinterrupt

I've written some code in Python with a GUI and there are two buttons (`BtnStart` , `BtnShutdown`). With hitting the `BtnStart` a sensor permanetly recieves data and the script plots it. While the script is executing I want to hit the `BtnShutdown` and the script should end. I don't care about a clean up, I'll see my data on the plot. The data is recieved via a USB port from a Arduino Nano. I am working with Python 2.7 and Jessie on a Pi.

Here's my problem:

The script simply won't close itself, when `BtnShutdown` is clicked. To close it I have to do a `^C` and then hit the `BtnShutdown`. But thats not what i want.
I googled a bit about Interrupts but I only found something with GPIO ports and I don't think that I use them (the base script was not mine, I am just editing it). Or is there a way I can make the statements from `ShutdownGTM` more important than anything else?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Of course, some code:

```
def ShutdownGTM(self):
    print "Shutdown"
    picamera.PiCamera().close()   
    sid = os.getpid()                                              
    p = psutil.Process(sid)
    p.terminate()

def StartGTM(self):
    s = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600)
    s.isOpen()
    time.sleep(5)
    measureanddostuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer. You should try `sys.exit` in your `ShutdownGTM`.

Comment: Thank you! u r the best! I love you <3